# MPMoviePlayer video quality is not the same as original video quality on Youtube

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to play YouTube videos in IOS App and it working fine. But the issue is in quality, Quality is not same in MPMoviePlayer as video's are on YouTube. 
I have tried different approaches but did not get any solutions. 
like : YTPlayerView,LBYouTube etc...
Please help me if anyone have a solution for that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I read this somewhere...it working fine...

Try it by using

**`LBYouTubePlayerViewController`**

It is a subclass of `MPMoviePlayerViewController.`

`LBYouTubeView`  is a small view that is able to display YouTube videos in a `MPMoviePlayerController`.

you have choice to select between high-quality and standard quality.

`LBYouTubeView` doesn't use `UIWebView` which makes it faster .

Comment: Thanks for Answer 
I have tried *LBYouTubePlayerViewController* But not working,
Problem is when start playing video it is playing in MPMoviePlayer 
and as i read about it- MpMoviePlayer strem video based on network connection speed.